# Python Celery Task.update_state potentially blocks forever

Tags: python, celery, amqp

I am using Celery current_task to update a tasks progression. It works 99% of the time then will hang indefinitely. celery 3.0.x with RabbitMQ backend

```
current_task.update_state(state=state,
            meta= { 'progress' : progress })
```

[UPDATE]

So there appears to be deadlock occurring in the celery amqp backend,

```
def _store_result(self, task_id, result, status, traceback=None):
    """Send task return value and status."""
    with self.mutex:
        with self.app.amqp.producer_pool.acquire(block=True) as pub:
            ..........
```

Investigating a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with the kombu connection pool limit, was able to solve this issue by increasing broker_pool_limit from default

```
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=100
```